# Bind to a page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I am confused about something really simple in ASP.NET. I have seen many times a pattern where there is a three column table, with label, control and validator in each column, which I can put together pretty straightforwardly. However, what I don't understand is how to handle binding here. If I have a table with Customer record and FirstName, LastName and PhoneNum, I want a page that takes customerId in the query string, and binds that record to the page so that I can use Bind() as the text box values.

However, there is no DataSource property on the page to bind the record to. I know I am missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a DataSource Control such as a SqlDataSource and use it in conjunction with a Data Control that will bind to the previous datasource control like a DetailsView. Then you configure your DataSource control to only bring in data for the particular CustomerId; the SqlDataSource allows you to use a QueryStringParameter as part of the select statement to the database.

Each of the above controls have wizards that will allow you to easily configure them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your controls (labels, textboxes, validators) inside a control that accepts data binding (ie. FormView, GridView, Repeater, etc.etc.) and then bind your data to that control.